# Reusing session cookie in HttpClient calls

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, session-cookies, dotnet-httpclient

I have a Web API 2 project using cookie-based sessions for our internal use. I have `/api/login` and `/api/logout` actions created and it works fine using a browser to access it.

I'm now trying to create a C# client to communicate with the API by using `HttpClient`. I can log in fine using:

```cs
Uri loginUri =  new Uri("http://localhost/api", "login");
HttpResponseMessage response = _http.PostAsJsonAsync(loginUri, loginModel).Result;
```

And I can get the session id string from the cookie by

```cs
var cookies = _httpHandler.CookieContainer.GetCookies(uri);
if (cookies["session_id"] != null)
    sessionID = cookies["session_id"].Value;
```

**My question is**: for every subsequent request including the logout request, how do I include the `session_id` cookie in the request header? I would like to reuse the `HttpClient` object for the duration of the session if possible. I saw [this question and answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13041354/how-to-generalize-login-action-and-logout-when-using-web-api-httpclient), but it's for calling login, performing the operation, and logout in the same request.

Thanks!

Comment: Just out of curiosity, why do you want to use session with web api?

Comment: Which request header do you need to put the session id in?  If it is the cookie header, then that will happen automatically.  Otherwise use DefaultRequestHeaders.

Comment: @kaptan I need to keep a TCP connection alive with a legacy server.
@DarrelMiller I need it in the `Set-Cookie` header. I tried. When I'm sending out the next request, the `session-id` cookie is not there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up going back and used the same **FormsAuthentication** methods I used in my MVC project. So after calling my custom **MembershipProvider**, I used **FormsAuthentication** methods to set and keep track of my session cookies. I called `FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie()` to log in and `FormsAuthentication.SignOut()` to log out.